# IE10 print preview not appearing for some pages

Tags: internet-explorer-10

Does anyone know why in IE10 the print preview option appears for some web pages but not others?

I have an internal website that doesn't have print preview for some reason (and as I coded it, I've not explicitly disabled this option).

Comment: Have the same question for Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973479 (Unable to print or view the print preview of a webpage in Internet Explorer)

> This issue can occur for one or more of the following scenarios:
>
> Scenario 1: Your video card or video driver is outdated or corrupt.
>   Note Outdated or corrupted printer drivers can also cause script
>   errors when printing from Internet Explorer
>
> Scenario 2: You may not have printer permissions assigned
>
> Scenario 3: **Protected Mode is enabled for the Internet security zone
>   of the web page**
>
> Scenario 4: There is an issue with temporary folders on your user
>   account and the Low folder under the %TEMP% location has been deleted

Comment: duDE, none of these are the issue as it works for SOME webpages but not others.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Can you show the HTML of your self-coded site?

Answer (score 1):

Well for everyone out there that has been trying to fix a no print or print preview problem with Internet Explorer I have found the answer to the problem. It’s a totally different fix not mentioned in any of the 100s of webpages I have been researching for over a month now. The most common fixs that DON’T work are listed below at least they didn’t work for me. Below them is how I fix it. I can’t believe that even Microsoft has no suggestions about this.

The dosen’t work section:
Scenario 1: Your video card or video driver is outdated or corrupt. Note Outdated or corrupted printer drivers can also cause script errors when printing from Internet Explorer

Scenario 2: You may not have printer permissions assigned

Scenario 3: Protected Mode is enabled for the Internet security zone of the web page

Scenario 4: There is an issue with temporary folders on your user account and the Low folder under the %TEMP% location has been deleted

My long awaited fix for no printing on Explorer. This is for Win 7 32 bit but should work with 64 bit Explorer too. Finally something different to try. It just so happens that when Explorer installs it often fails to resister some of it’s DLL files. There are complicated ways to register DLL files but I and going to give you a simple way to do it. First open My Computer and go to “C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer” open up the folder “Internet Explorer” and click “type” to arrange the files by type. This puts all the DLLs together. Now double click on the first DLL. You will get an “open with” box. Click on “Browse” and go to “C:\windows\system32” and find the file called “regsvr32.exe”. Choose that file to open all DLL files. Now go back to the first DLL in the “C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer” folder and double click on it. You will probably get an error message that it can’t be found. This only means it’s already registered and operating. Double click each DLL one by one and you will start to notice that some will say “registration successful”. Finish them all in that folder.